# c# and mysql, insert into throws exeotuib

Tags: c#, mysql

When i use this  in c#.

```
Registration.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `DBname`.`tablename`(`id`,`column1`,`column2`,`column3`)VALUES(6, x, x, x);";
```

It outputs this exception. When i used same command in mysql workbench query it doenst work. I know this isnt safe and if someone knows more safe method that works i would be gratefull.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'x' in 'field list''
```

Comment: is `id` column is an foreign key?

Comment: watch to your columns types if there character x must inside ''

Comment: You  must single quote 'x' or mysql will take that as a column name.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look in to using prepared statements if your data is coming from untrusted sources (such as a user). However, this should also help you solve your problem.

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myDb.Table WHERE col_A = @val_a AND col_B = @val_b", MySqlConn.conn);

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val_a", someUserInput);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val_b", otherUserInput);
myCommand.Prepare();

MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

I believe that is something that should help get you going in the right direction.

Comment: so in that part someuserinput is where i put a variable. and how should look in my case so i can see correctly

Comment: `"INSERT INTO `DBname`.`tablename`(`id`,`column1`,`column2`,`column3`)VALUES(6, x, x, x);"` would be:
`myCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO DBName.Table (col_1, col_2, col_3) VALUES (@val_1, @val_2, @val_3);")`
`myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val_1", valueForVal_1); //...etc...`